# How do regular expressions work in selenium?

Tags: regex, selenium, fitnesse, selenium-fitnesse-bridge

I want to store part of an id, and throw out the rest. For example, I have an html element with an id of 'element-12345'. I want to throw out 'element-' and keep '12345'. How can I accomplish this?

I can capture and echo the value, like this:

```
| storeAttribute | //pathToMyElement@id | myId |
| echo | ${!-myId-!} | |
```

When I run the test, I get something like this:

```
| storeAttribute | //pathToMyElement@id | myId |
| echo | ${myId} | element-12345 |
```

I'm recording with the Selenium IDE, and copying the test over into Fitnesse, using the Selenium Bridge fixture. The problem is I'm using a clean database each time I run the test, with random ids that I need to capture and use throughout my test.

Comment: +1 because selenium is an excellent tool!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution is to use the JavaScript `replace()` function with `storeEval`:

```
| storeAttribute | //pathToMyElement@id                                   | elementID |
| storeEval      | '${elementID}'.replace("element-", "")                 | myID      |
```

Now if I echo `myID` I get just the ID:

```
| echo | ${myID} | 12345 |
```

Answer (score 2):

/element-(\d+)/i

That's a regular expression that would capture the numbers after the dash.

Comment: Thanks! Now where would that go in my code?

| storeAttribute | //pathToMyElement@id | myId |

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I've never used Selenium before. I posted the regular expression hoping someone who had used it before could come along and help you use it. I'll do some research and see if I can come up with an answer though :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this *might* work:

```
| storeAttribute | fn:replace(//pathToMyElement@id,"^element-","") | myId |
```

To do regex requires XPath 2.0 - not sure which version Selenium implements.